# What's the best way to encrypt crypto seeds?

Tags: encryption, cryptocurrency

I would like to encrypt cryptocurrency wallet seeds (12 to 24-word passphrases) for replication and secure preservation. The seeds would be in a .txt or .rtf format before encryption. I would like to be able to send these over the internet with peace of mind. Encryption should hold for at the very least 60 years. What software would you recommend and why?

Comment: This isn't a software recommendation site, but I can say that you might want to look at GnuPG's symmetric encryption feature. If you need the software to be easy for others to use, you could consider 7zip which supports AES encryption, although it's not done quite as well as GnuPG.

Comment: 60 years is a long time. For that amount of time you may need to consider quantum computing. Key / password management may be considered more important than the protocol used though.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Presumably he'll be using symmetric encryption, so quantum computing isn't quite as relevant (although it is for the cryptocurrency he's probably using).